# $\chi_f$ not coprime to $p \in K[X]$ with $p(f)(v) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be a $K$ vector space and $f: V \to V$ $K$-linear. Let $v \in V \setminus \{0\}$ and $p \in K[X]$ with $p(f)(v) = 0$. How does one proof that $p$ and the characteristic polynomial $\chi_f$ are not coprime?

---

Ideas:
As the roots of $\chi_f$ are the eigenvalues of $f$, there must be an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such chat $X - \lambda$ divides $p$. By Cayley-Hamilton, we have $\chi_f(f)(v) = 0$. But I have no idea how to get any knowledge about $p$ via $p(f)(v) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the set $I = \{ g \in K[x] \mid g(f)(v) = 0 \}$, i.e. the set of polynomials in $f$ that annihilate $v$.  Check that it's an ideal.

Recall that $K[x]$ is a principal ideal domain when $K$ is a field, so $I$ is principally generated.  We'll call its generator the **minimal polynomial** (of $f$ with respect to $v$).

Of course $p, \chi_f$ are both elements of $I$, so the minimal polynomial (of $f$ with respect to $v$) divides them both.